# MagSafe 3 cable failures

Tags: usb, charging, magsafe

My MagSafe 3 cable (for an M1 MacBook Pro 14" from late 2021) refused to charge the laptop this morning despite it running as usual from the battery. (Both the Apple-supplied mains charger and a car USB-C charger could charge my phone, so it's the cable or the laptop.) However it came good with a reboot of the laptop.

**Question 1:** Has this happened to you and did you figure out the cause? (It did get cold overnight, perhaps -3C, and MenuMeters reported a CPU temperature of 3C first-thing. However even at 15C charging did not occur.)

**Question 2:** Is there any chance it would have come good by itself? i.e., avoiding the reboot.

**Question 3:** If I had a USB-C to USB-C "power" cable, would it have worked? i.e. avoided the need to reboot.

Comment: What is the specified working temperature range for the laptop?

Comment: The fact that the charging started working after a reboot suggests it's not the cable, but the laptop itself. However, always start with the cheapest part. See if the laptop will charge with another cable.

Comment: @benwiggy: it did come good with a reboot. I also conclude that there is some glitch in the power management in these laptops.

Comment: @SolarMike: I'd just observe that if the power management allows the machine to come back from sleep and yet refuses to charge (without a reboot) then things are a bit smelly.

Comment: If things are too cold then they tend to smell less…

Comment: FWIW, I have a 16" M1 Pro MBP, and I've not seen any problems with charging. Apparently you can't reset the SMC on M1: restarting (while plugged in!) is enough. If you keep experiencing problems, I'd take it to an Apple Store for evaluation, while it's still reasonably new.

Comment: Are you noticing it not charge after 80%? That's a feature, not a bug. It is called optimized charging. It keeps your battery healthy by limiting ghr charge to 80%

Comment: Have you run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)?

Comment: @anonymous: I'm familiar with that, yes. I've edited my question to clarify what happened. It got down to ~ 10% remaining battery power despite being plugged in to a power source.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: thanks, I did not know about this. If it recurs I'll try it.